# make links between ext4 and fat32

Tags: android, linux, shell, fat32, ln

it is used in android phone. Because my ROM is big enough(around 8G), and my SDCard has been full with various files, so i want to link a big file stored in ROM to SDCard so as to save the treasure space of SDCard( **the big file cannot be identified by a software except it is in /sdcard patition** ) first i take an test to validate the method: try to link a file /data/test.mp3 to /sdcard/test_fat32.mp3, then in the terminal (#su), i tried to make a symbolic link like this :

`ln -s /data/test.mp3 /sdcard/test_fat32.mp3`

but failed:

`ln: /sdcard/test_fat32.mp3: Operation not permitted`

Googling for a while, and i found that i cannot create symbolic links with fat32, i dont want to format the SDCard to `ext4`, because i want to make such an app to share with my friends. you surely cannot demand everyone of the format, what's more, maybe many apps cannot identify `ext4` files. does anyone have a good idea to realize it? any help appreciated!

Comment: There is normally nothing related to FAT32 as the source is on an ext4 filesystem and your using a symbolic link. Normally it should have worked even if the first folder of the target doesn't exist. On a real Linux system it work in that way without root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FAT32 have no data type to save links. My best guess is to format SD to ext2 and use something like ext2fsd if you want access it from windows. Or reconsider the fact that you really need this.

Comment: thx,is there any other way to establish relations between ext4 and fat32 file? e.g. method such as mapping, or some other ways to access inner files and fake the app that it is a file in /sdcard?

Comment: Change SD mount path to /sdcard/ext or something like that, if you have root access. Have no other ideas for now, sorry.

Comment: @keltar : There is nothing to create on a FAT32 system since the source use ext4. Indeed, if you do this kind of command for creating symbolic link from an ext4 partition target a file/folder FAT32 drive work under real Linux without root access.

Comment: @user2284570 I don't understand what you saying. The last argument to `ln` is source, not destination.

Comment: @keltar : Not on the android version.

Comment: @user2284570 just checked. As expected, it is a complete nonsense - `ln [-s] <target> <name>`. Reversing argument order of standard program would be insane.